# Magento 1.9.0.1 CE Product Image Upload - File was not uploaded

Tags: product, image, upload

I recently installed a new installation of Magento CE 1.9.0.1.

I am attempting to upload my product images Catalog->Manage Products->Edit Product->Images

Then I Browse Files and choose my .jpg file.

I then click the Upload Files button.

I get a red box that says, "File was not uploaded."  I checked the code and modified this section:  throw new Exception('File was not uploaded. Error='.$this->_file['error'], $code); in lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

The error code I get is 0

Which I thought meant success....so I am very confused.

I have my tmp dirs all set to 777 including the one listed in phpinfo()

Any ideas where I am going wrong or what I need to do to upload image files?

Thanks,

Jim Nickel

Comment: Bump....I really am hoping someone has some suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

So....I have to assume it was some permissions issue, but I had already put everything to 777.

Anyway...I changed my php.ini to point to a directory inside my websites home directory var/tmp in my case and now it works fine.

Jim